# How to fix Search Bar functionality in a List View?

Tags: java, android, listview, search

**1.** I have a `ListView` that contains images, persons names, persons birthdays. 
I have created a search bar where it can be used to search the content in the `ListView`.

**2.** I've added to search bar **addTextChangedListener**, and in **TextWatcher onTextChanged** to get filter from adapter but as result when I search for a person name nothing happens.

Also while debugging I have checked that I am receiving data from the Adapter and **onTextchanged** the char seq entered.

**3.** Main Activity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private Button btn_add,btn_edit,btn_delete;
    private StudentsListAdapter test1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String username = intent.getStringExtra("Username");
        String password = intent.getStringExtra("Password");

        btn_add = findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        btn_edit = findViewById(R.id.btn_edit);
        btn_delete = findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);

        EditText search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchFilter);

        ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.li_view);

        ArrayList<PersonInfo> students1 = new ArrayList<>();

        students1.add(new PersonInfo(android.R.drawable.btn_star, "Julien", "03/27/1998"));
        students1.add(new PersonInfo(android.R.drawable.btn_star, "Jamaica", "03/27/1998"));
        students1.add(new PersonInfo(android.R.drawable.btn_star, "Bara", "03/27/1998"));
        students1.add(new PersonInfo(android.R.drawable.btn_star, "Bere", "03/27/1998"));

        test1 = new StudentsListAdapter(
                this, R.layout.adapter_view_layout, students1, true);
        listView1.setAdapter(test1);

        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                (MainActivity.this).test1.getFilter().filter(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        if(username.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin")){

            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Started.");
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.li_view);

            ArrayList<PersonInfo> students = new ArrayList<>();


            students.add(new PersonInfo(android.R.drawable.btn_star, "Amaizing", "03/27/1998"));
            students.add(new PersonInfo(android.R.drawable.btn_star, "Jamaica", "03/27/1998"));
            students.add(new PersonInfo(android.R.drawable.btn_star, "But", "03/27/1998"));
            students.add(new PersonInfo(android.R.drawable.btn_star, "Carmen", "03/27/1998"));


            test1 = new StudentsListAdapter(
                    this, R.layout.adapter_view_layout, students, true);
            listView.setAdapter(test1);

            search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    (MainActivity.this).test1.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                    test1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });


        }
            else if (username.equals("user") && password.equals("user"))
            {
                ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.li_view);

                ArrayList<PersonInfo> students = new ArrayList<>();


                students.add(new PersonInfo(android.R.drawable.btn_star, "AJ", "03/27/1998"));

                test1 = new StudentsListAdapter(
                        this, R.layout.adapter_view_layout, students,false);
                listView.setAdapter(test1);


            }
    }
}
```

Student List Adapter class:

```
    public class StudentsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PersonInfo>{
    private Context contxt;
    private int rsrc;
    private List<PersonInfo> persons;
    private boolean isAdmin;


    public StudentsListAdapter( Context context, int resource, List<PersonInfo> _persons,  boolean _isAadmin) {
        super(context, resource, _persons);
        contxt = context;
        rsrc = resource;
        persons=_persons;
        isAdmin = _isAadmin;
    }

    Filter myFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<PersonInfo> tempList=new ArrayList<PersonInfo>();
            // Add the filter code here
            if(constraint != null && persons!=null) {
                int length= persons.size();
                int i=0;
                while(i<length){
                    PersonInfo item= persons.get(i);
                    //do whatever you wanna do here
                    //adding result set output array
                    String name = item.getName();
                    if(name.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString()))  {
                        tempList.add(item);
                    }

                    i++;
                }
                //following two lines is very important
                //as publish result can only take FilterResults users
                filterResults.values = tempList;
                filterResults.count = tempList.size();
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint, FilterResults results) {
            persons = (ArrayList<PersonInfo>) results.values;
            if (results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(contxt);
        View view = inflater.inflate(rsrc, null,false);

        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imgP);
        TextView pName = view.findViewById(R.id.txtView2);
        TextView pBirthday = view.findViewById(R.id.txtView3);

        Button btn_add = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        Button btn_edit = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_edit);
        Button btn_delete = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);

        btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(contxt,AddItems.class)
                        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                contxt.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        if(isAdmin) {
            btn_add.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btn_edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btn_delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            btn_add.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btn_edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btn_delete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        PersonInfo p = persons.get(position);


        imageView.setImageDrawable(contxt.getResources().getDrawable(p.getImage()));
        pBirthday.setText(p.getBirthday());
        pName.setText(p.getName());

       btn_edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               persons.get(position);
           }
       });

        btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                removePerson(position);
            }
        });
        return view;


    }
}
```

PersonInfo class:

```
    public class PersonInfo {
    private int image;
    private String name;
    private String birthday;

    public PersonInfo(int image, String name, String birthday) {
        this.image = image;
        this.name = name;
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(String birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }
}
```

Main Activity XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/searchFilter"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/li_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        tools:layout_algignParentStart="true" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Adapter XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgP"
        android:layout_width="399dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_weight="66.6" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="33.3">

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/txtView2"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtView2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView3" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_add"
            android:layout_width="69dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtView3"
           android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:text="ADD" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="69dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_add"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtView3"
            android:id="@+id/btn_edit"
            android:text="edit"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_edit"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtView3"
            android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
            android:text="Delete"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: You have not overidded the getFilter() method in adapter class

Comment: where is your filter code in adapter class.?

Comment: Hi @AtifAbbAsi, i have missed to add the Filter code and i am trying to add it in my adapter class.

Comment: If you are still stuck, try removed all the filter code in the adapter. Then in **PersonInfo class**, override `toString()` method to return name. Hope that helps!

Comment: To use a custom filter, there should be 2 lists for the data. One is an unfiltered/backup/all_data list which contains all the data. The other one is filtered/working/data list which is the result to show on UI. My blog on listview may help: http://programandroidlistview.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

So I checked and what you need to do is add getter in the StudentsListAdapter

```
   List<PersonInfo> getPersons() {
    return persons;
}
```

then in your MainActivity you can get the list and find the needed item. I made the search and if found it shows Toast for now, but you can adjust it as you want.
You don't need the text listener in the Adapter.

```
  test1 = new StudentsListAdapter(
            this, R.layout.adapter, students1, true);
    listView1.setAdapter(test1);

    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            for(PersonInfo person: test1.getPersons()) {
                if(person.getName().startsWith(s.toString())) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ITEM FOUND" + person.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, i have tried using this code but i still can't receive the items details, you can take a look [here](https://i.imgur.com/vqbULmM.png). Thank you!

Comment: @FearLessAZ My code does not provide complete solution. But inside of the if statement you can get the item which was found and then do your actions with it :) Because checking your app the search was not working at all, so I created this code.

Answer (score 0):

It was not working because you haven't overriden getFilter(). You have to override the getFilter() in StudentsListAdapter. Please look at the code below.

```
List<PersonInfo> listFiltered = new ArrayList<PersonInfo>();

public StudentsListAdapter( Context context, int resource, List<PersonInfo> _persons,  boolean _isAadmin) {
    //...
    this.listFiltered= _persons;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence c) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (c.length() == 0) {
            results.count = persons.size();
            results.values = persons;
        } else {
            List<PersonInfo> resultsData = new ArrayList<>();

// This is just for your reference please get the data accordingly

            for (PersonInfo s : persons)
                if (s.getName().contains(c)) resultsData.add(s);
            results.count = resultsData.size();
            results.values = resultsData;
        }

        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence c, FilterResults results) {
        listFiltered = (ArrayList<PersonInfo>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
  };
}
```

And also override the getCount() and getItem()

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listFiltered.size();
}

@Override
public PersonInfo getItem(int position) {
    return listFiltered.get(position);
}
```

Comment: Hi, you're right i have not override the getFilter() in StudentsListAdapter i have added the code you mentioned but i got errors.Could you please take a look [here](https://i.imgur.com/rXOH6FQ.png) about the errors i got. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer but i still got issues on listFiletered variable and on for (String s : list) [here](https://i.imgur.com/40ZpFkM.png) check it out please, thank you!

Comment: Dude, you haven't added the "listFiltered" variable as Global Variable. Look at the first line of the code. And also on which item of PersonInfo object you want to search on. Its just a sample I gave you. Please post your PersonInfo Object also if you cant figure it out, i can help.

Comment: Hi @PrashanthVerma,thanks for replying back i have added "listFiltered" as global variable, i just want to search for person name in my PersonInfo object, my PersonInfo object already posted around here, but i tried to change the code where you mentioned "get the data accordingly" [here](https://i.imgur.com/dgd9Dos.png) but i still got errors in the if statement and on getItem(). Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for updating the code but as result while debugging when i write let's say "Jamaica" it gives me "Test" person name. Here are the results [Debugging result](https://i.imgur.com/Ood77fN.png), [Search bar result](https://i.imgur.com/e1AVv8J.png). Why is this happening ? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Please put below code in your getfilter() method

```
Filter myFilter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
     FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();   
     ArrayList<PersonInfo> tempList=new ArrayList<PersonInfo>();
     // Add the filter code here
     if(constraint != null && persons!=null) {
         int length= persons.size();
         int i=0;
            while(i<length){
                PersonInfo item= persons.get(i);
                //do whatever you wanna do here
                //adding result set output array   
                String name = item.getName(); 
         if(name.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString()))  {                  
                tempList.add(item);
              }

                i++;
            }
            //following two lines is very important
            //as publish result can only take FilterResults users
            filterResults.values = tempList;
            filterResults.count = tempList.size();
      }
      return filterResults;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint, FilterResults results) {
      persons = (ArrayList<PersonsInfo>) results.values;
      if (results.count > 0) {
       notifyDataSetChanged();
      } else {
          notifyDataSetInvalidated();
      }  
  }
 };
```

Comment: Hi @Sandeep dhiman, i have tried your code but i am still wondering what should be the if statement.. Thank you!

Comment: @FearLessAZ please remove that if statement and try, it will work

Comment: Hi @Sandeepdhiman,I have removed the if statement if you could please take a look at [debugging results](https://i.imgur.com/YlFSP6F.png),It returns the right length and char seq but when i search for any person it still look like [this](https://i.imgur.com/lnKi3ou.png), where "Jamaica" the user i look for already [exist](https://i.imgur.com/H94o5QK.png). Thank you for your reply looking to hear from you we are very close to solve this issue.

Comment: I have tried the code you updated but now the app stop working when i type something in the search bar, and i have check the debugging result that the if statement is not returning anything. Please take a look [here](https://i.imgur.com/ZdWTqJO.png) Thank you!

Comment: debug your code then what you are passing in filter method in Ontextchanged method

Comment: here is the [result](https://i.imgur.com/oCjnOuy.png) of onTextChanged, and i am applying this one myFilter() instead of getFilter(): (MainActivity.this).test1.myFilter.filter(s);

Comment: Please complete adapter code here that you are using

Comment: sorry i didn't understand quality what you mean.

Comment: Please post your complete adapter code here that you are using

Comment: I have updated the StudentListAdapter code in my post above check it out please thank you.

Comment: why dont you override getFilter() method in your adapter

Comment: Like this @Override
    public Filter getFilter()
    {
       
        return new Filter(){};
    }

Comment: I have override getFilter() method and the app keeps stop working [here](https://i.imgur.com/bEyDBrm.png) is the result of debugging.

Comment: check you logcat why your app is crashing?

Comment: I have checked the logcat and it's crashing in this line 
PersonInfo p = persons.get(position); [here](https://i.imgur.com/2t8pQtb.png) is the result, knowing that it was working before adding the override getFilter() method.

Comment: I have debugged my code it's not returning the position of the items, but as i told u when i removed the override of getFilter() it returns back the position without any errors. It's weird..